# onPressed ElevatedButton call automatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Initially I want to know why onPress call automatically while rendering. After getting above issue I tried solving it in a number of ways like

**WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback** and **Future.delayed** . Code

```
class ShadowBtn {
  static Widget drawBtn(double width, double height, String text, myFunc) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        ///onPressed: () => myFunc,
        onPressed: () {
          myFunc();
        },
        child: Text(text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Some solutions said to update onPress like
`onPressed: () => myFunc`

I simply call it like

```
ShadowBtn.drawBtn(321.w, 61.h, "SEND OTP", openScreen(context))
```

Where openScreen

```
openScreen(context) {
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/dashboard', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  });

  // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  //   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  //       '/dashboard', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  // });
}
```

After trying all the solution. I didn't find any proper way to handle it.

Comment: From your current state, `onPressed: () { myFunc();},` supposed to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openScreen` function is called when passed as a parameter.

```
ShadowBtn.drawBtn(321.w, 61.h, "SEND OTP", openScreen(context))
```

Something like this should work:

```
ShadowBtn.drawBtn(321.w, 61.h, "SEND OTP", () => openScreen(context));

class ShadowBtn {
  static Widget drawBtn(double width, double height, String text, void Function() myFunc) {
...
        onPressed: () {
          myFunc();
        },
...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While passing the parameter you are actually not passing , instead making a `function call`, but `function definition` needs to be passed in the `parameter`.

so try using `(){function()}`, so now the `definition` is passed, and `function is not called.`

Change

```
ShadowBtn.drawBtn(321.w, 61.h, "SEND OTP", openScreen(context))
```

to

```
ShadowBtn.drawBtn(321.w, 61.h, "SEND OTP", (){openScreen(context)})
```